# Converting UTM Dataset using QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, utm

I have a dataset with coordinates in UTM. I want to covert these coordinates using QGIS to lat long. I've tried doing it multiple times now, and the end result converted coordinates are not coming out right. Here is what I did:

1. Opened the data in QGIS as a text delimited layer. Set the X field to easting, and the Y field to northing. Set the Geometry CRS to WGS 84 / UTM Zone 17S. Saved and added to map.
2. Used the export features tool to create a CSV file in QGIS of the saved datapoints. I set the CRS to WGS 84 and the geometry to AS_XY. I then saved the new CSV file.

The resulting CSV file has lat long coordinates, but they are way off from what they should be, and I am not sure why.

Comment: Some examples please of your input UTM84-17S data and your results. Also, a screen shot of your export screen.

Comment: You can also try the 'Reproject Layer' from the Processing Toolbox. This way, you can visually check the result (make sure the canvas is set to the right crs)

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! It looks like you have a coordinate system problem, see if any of the suggestions at https://ihatecoordinatesystems.com/ help.